# Как получить юзера после логина

Tags: spring, безопасность, java

Доброго времени суток. Я пробовал сделать простую форму логина с использованием Spring Security и вроде как все работает хорошо, юзер логиниться, я могу узнать имя залогиневшегося юзера, пароль. Но как мне получить именно юзера как объект из моей базы данных? 
Т.к мне нужна вся информация касающаяся моего юзера из базы, а не данные UserDetails.

Вот метод, которые вызывается после того как юзер залогинился:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/overview", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showOverview(ModelMap map) {

 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
 UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
 }
 return "overview";
 }
```

Вот как тут вместо userDetails получить user из БД?

Ниже представлен UserDetailsServiceImpl сервис:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

 @Autowired
 private UserDAO userDAO;

 @Autowired
 private UserAssembler userAssembler;

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
 User user = userDAO.findByEmail(username);

 if(null == user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
 return userAssembler.buildUserFromUser(user);
 }
}
```

А это Assembler:

```
@Service("assembler")
public class UserAssembler {

 @Autowired
 private UserDAO userDAO;

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public User buildUserFromUser(net.viralpatel.contact.model.User user) {
 String role = "ROLE_USER";//userEntityDAO.getRoleFromUserEntity(userEntity);

 Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
 authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role));

 return new User(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод loadUserByUsername() должен возвращать UserDetails. У вас он сейчас возвращает User, который реализует UserDetails. Ничто не мешает вам сделать свой класс, например, CustomUser, который бы наследовался от User и имел в себе любые данные о пользователе (можно только его id, а можно и всю сущность из БД). Поэтому вам достаточно будет изменить UserAssembler.buildUserFromUser(), чтобы он возвращал CustomUser.

(Имейте в виду, что если в CustomUser вы будете хранить сущность из БД, то есть вероятность получить ошибку, т.к. сущность на время станет deattached и при её использовании вы можете словить исключение. Поэтому можно хранить только id пользователя и в необходимых местах по этому id подгружать весь объект из БД.)

Comment: Ясно, а подскажите правильно ли будет сделать так: юзер залогинился, теперь я могу получить getPrincipal, и получить логин залогиневшегося юзера. Предположим у меня в DAO классе есть метод findByLogin(Sting login). И вот уже с помощью это метода, зная логин аутентифицированного юзера, получить юзера из БД. Или это не очень хорошая практика?

Comment: Вы можете так сделать, если хотите. Но лично я бы сделал всё тоже самое, только вместо логина использовал бы id из БД, потому что: а) Long занимает меньше чем String б) поиск по числу в БД, скорее всего, будет быстрее поиска по строке в) id пользователя это, обычно, primary key и индекс для него уже есть, а вот для логина нужно создавать и при этом не забыть сделать его уникальным.

Comment: @Slava Semushin  "Поэтому можно хранить только id пользователя и в необходимых местах по этому id подгружать весь объект из БД." - а что мешает хранить другие данные в своей имплиментации UserDetails, копируя их из сущности юзера в БД, теп самым уменьшив количество запросов к бд, а при изменении свойств сущности юзера менять их и в UserDetails?

Comment: @Slava Semushin, ясно, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Может конечно я предложу топорно, но в контроллере сделать запрос к базе (мб для этого у тебя есть класс), где в качестве параметра указать юзернейм пользователя..